# DISM Apply-Image on the same previously captured partition

Tags: dism

After capturing a Windows 10 image with

```
dism /capture-image /imagefile:i:\myimage.wim /capturedir:d:\ /name:myimage
```

when I try to apply the image to the previously captured dir `d:\` with

```
dism /apply-image /imagefile:i:\myimage.wim /applydir:d:\ /Index:1
```

I get an `Error 5: Access denied`

My workarounds are one of the following:

1. `rmdir /s /q d:\`
2. with `diskpart`: `select volume d` and `format quick fs=ntfs label=Windows`

Is there a simpler way?